# Handling invalid requests with koa-router and koa-mount

Tags: koa, koa-router

My app uses koa-router, and it mounts the router using koa-mount, as in:

```
var Router = require('koa-router');
var mount = require('koa-mount');

app = koa();

var router = new Router();
router.get('/foo', function *() { this.body = { success: true }));

app
  .use(mount('/api', router.middleware()))
  .use(RedisBoot)
;
```

The desired behavior is that **a route that starts with `api` that isn't defined should give a 503** or something. Instead, the request falls through to the RedisBoot handler. I've tried adding additional rules at the start and end of `router` but for some reason they do not seem to be being called.

I notice that newer versions of koa-router supported nested routes and have some other nice features, so maybe it would be easier to get this working now without koa-mount?

Comment: What is the 'RedisBoot' middleware?

Comment: It is part of an Ember deployment scheme, which serves a static `index.html` file taken from Redis if no other routes match.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of mounting the router directly to the parent app, create a secondary koa app (they're not heavyweight constructs so it shouldn't be a performance issue).

In this sub-app, add the router as the first middleware, add a catch-all handler as the second middleware, then mount the sub-app to the main app under `/api`.

```
var Router = require('koa-router');
var mount = require('koa-mount');

var app = koa();
var subApp = koa();

var router = new Router();
router.get('/foo', function *() { this.body = { success: true }));

subApp
  .use(router.middleware())
  .use(function *() { ... throw 503 or something... })
;

app
  .use(mount('/api', subApp))
  .use(RedisBoot)
;
```